# executor.map not working when i running python script

Tags: python

I have a problem when I run this program, I get a black blank output without any process, but when I CTRL + C I get an error message like this.

```
File "name.py", line 119, in <module>
    executor.map(main, emailist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 644, in __exit__
    self.shutdown(wait=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 236, in shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1011, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1027, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and this my code

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=work) as executor:
        executor.map(main, emailist)
detail = open('name.txt', 'r')
lines = detail.readlines()
hasil = len(lines)
det = open('wrong.txt', 'r')
lin = det.readlines()
has = len(lin)
```

Code for main

```py
def main(email):
    load_dotenv()

    username = os.getenv('username')
    password = os.getenv('password')
    endpoint = os.getenv('host')
    port = os.getenv('port')

    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    proxies_extension = proxies(username, password, endpoint, port)
    opt.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    opt.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    opt.add_extension(proxies_extension)
    opt.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    opt.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
    opt.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    opt.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    opt.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
    opt.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    opt.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    opt.add_argument("--disable-cookie-encryption")
    opt.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    opt.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36")    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
    )
    try:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(200)
        driver.get("https://localhost")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_first_name")))
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_first_name").send_keys("Jhon")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_last_name").send_keys("Kennedy")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_email").click()
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_email").send_keys(email)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_accepted_user_agreement").click()   
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_password").send_keys("1235123")
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "commit").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".flash")
            text = element.get_attribute('innerText')
            if "Success" in text:
                tx = open('name.txt', 'a+')
                tx.write('\n')
                tx.writelines(email)
                tx.close()  
                print(f'{Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}[#]{Fore.GREEN} {email} {Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}={Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX} Name')
                driver.quit()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            tx = open('wrong.txt', 'a+')
            tx.write('\n')
            tx.writelines(email)
            tx.close()  
            print(f'{Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}[#]{Fore.GREEN} {email} {Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}={Fore.LIGHTRED_EX} Die')
            driver.quit()
    except TimeoutException:
        tx = open('proxy.txt', 'a+')
        tx.write('\n')
        tx.writelines(email)
        tx.close()  
        print(f'{Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}[#]{Fore.GREEN} {email} {Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX}={Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX} Die')
        driver.quit()
```

And in my emailist ini txt with format

myemail@localhost

When I run this program on the VPS, the program only shows a black screen,

then i try to see the processes on my vps by using the ps aux command, i see chromedriver running but not displaying any output in my terminal.

Comment: Using main as a function like this a bad idea, reserve main for [`if/main`](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/#a-basic-python-main). Also you did not put the definition of your main function, or the emailist (sic).

Comment: we need to know what `main` and `emailist` look like

Comment: I'm already edit post , @Anentropic